# Facebook not able to scrape my url after moving Magento to subdirectory

Tags: facebook, magento, http-status-code-404, fetch, multistore

can someone help me on this issue.
I've created a Magetno multistore with each store in a subdirectory (e.g. domain.com/store1) I've copied the index.php file and the .htaccess file from the root directory of the Magento installation into the newly created subdirectory for the new shop and made some modifications in index.php file in order to make it work. Now the store in subdirectory is working but Facebook cant scrape the data from URL domain.com/store1. It's always showing Error 404: not found. Must I also change something in .htaccess file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I found out that I was missing a few steps. The website link below solved my problem
https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-to-Setup-Magento-with-Multiple-Stores-and-Domains